# is there std::mismatch for two unequal sized vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, std

I d like to compare two vectors where the second one might have more/less items than the first one.

```
v1 = 1,2,3,4,5

v2 = 1,0,3,4,5,6
```

As far as I understood, `std::mismatch` woNT do the trick. How could I detect the missing element in the v1?

Thanks in advance,

Orkun

Comment: Sort them and compare.

Comment: Have you tried set_difference? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/

Comment: Or simply compare to vectors with `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++14 adds two [additional overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) that accommodate different sized ranges

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2 >
std::pair<InputIt1,InputIt2>
    mismatch( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2 );

template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryPredicate >
std::pair<InputIt1,InputIt2>
    mismatch( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
              BinaryPredicate p );
```

You might be able to use these by setting `-std=c++1y` on gcc and clang

Comment: C++14 support might be a bit optimistic at the moment!

Comment: @Sean Indeed, libstdc++ [doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/894d25237202ccdf) contain those overloads, but looking at the latest libc++ [source](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm) I can find both of them. So clang + libc++ might be an option. Edit: The latest libstdc++ [source](http://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/HEAD:/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#l1334) includes them too.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`set_symmetric_difference()`**, but before this the source ranges must be ordered:

```
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2;

// ... Populate v1 and v2

// For the set_symmetric_difference algorithm to work, 
// the source ranges must be ordered!    
vector<int> sortedV1(v1);
vector<int> sortedV2(v2);

sort(sortedV1.begin(),sortedV1.end());
sort(sortedV2.begin(),sortedV2.end());

// Now that we have sorted ranges (i.e., containers), find the differences    
vector<int> vDifferences;

set_symmetric_difference(
    sortedV1.begin(), sortedV1.end(),
    sortedV2.begin(), sortedV2.end(),
    back_inserter(vDifferences));
```

After this, all different elements of these two vectors (i.e. either in `v1` or `v2`, but not both) will be stored in `vector<int> vDifferences`. For your example, it will be `{0, 2, 6}`.

> [...] Computes symmetric difference of two sorted ranges: the elements that are found in either of the ranges, but not in both of them are copied to the range beginning at d_first. The resulting range is also sorted. [...]

If you just need the missing elements in the `v1`, you can further scan this `vDifferences` against `sortedV1` to find them out.

Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780648/2589776) for more info.